# What does colons mean in Matlab when converting to Python?

Tags: python, matlab, converters

I am trying to convert a Matlab code to Python and mostly everything is quite simple to change. But I got stuck with this part when there appeared a lot of colons in one place. This is the original Matlab code:

```
for iii=1:nP-1  
    nnn=100;
    xxx=[X(iii):(X(iii+1)-X(iii))/nnn:X(iii+1)];
    fff=0;
    for j=1:2
        [U,V]=Hermite(X(iii:iii+1),j,xxx);
        fff=fff+U*Y(iii+j-1)+V*DY(iii+j-1);
    end
    figure(1), hold on, grid on, axis equal
    plot(xxx,fff,'r-','LineWidth',2.5);
    plot(X(iii:iii+1),Y(iii:iii+1),'ko','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',8)
end
```

I got it down to this in Python:

```
for iii in range(0,nP - 2):
    nnn = 100

    xxx = [X[iii]:(X[iii + 1] - X[iii]) / nnn:X[iii + 1]]
    fff = 0
    for j in range(0,1):
        [U, V] = Hermite(X[iii:iii + 1], j, xxx)
        fff = fff + U * Y(iii + j - 1) + V * DY[iii + j - 1]

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.grid("on")
    plt.axis("equal")
    plt.plot(xxx, fff, color='red',marker='o',linestyle='')
    plt.plot(X[iii:iii + 1], Y[iii:iii + 1], color='blue',marker='o',linestyle='')
    plt.show()
```

The part I'm stuck on is here:

```
xxx = [X[iii]:(X[iii + 1] - X[iii]) / nnn:X[iii + 1]]
```

I believe for someone who knows both languages pretty well it should be easy.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I meant colons, not semi colons. I edited my question

Comment: I see. In the meantime, you already got an answer. See also the [documentation of `:`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `a : b : c`  creates a sequence from a to c (inclusive if possible) using steps of b. Wrapping this further in brackets has no effect in this case, since a sequence is already a matrix (i.e. it is true that `a:b:c` is equivalent to `[a:b:c]` ). Therefore

```
[ X(iii)  :  (X(iii+1) - X(iii)) / nnn  :  X(iii+1) ];
```

is a sequence:

- from `X[iii]` (whatever that evaluates to),
- to `X[iii + 1]`
- using steps of `(X[iii + 1] - X[iii]) / nnn`

The equivalent in python is `range( start, end, steps)` if dealing with integers, or `numpy.arange` for floats, but with one caveat. Matlab treats the endpoind as 'inclusive', whereas python treats it as 'exclusive'. Which means you'll have to adjust your endpoint slightly to get the same range (typically you can do that by passing the value 'endpoint+step' to `range`, to make this your new 'excluded' endpoint for python)

To show you what I mean, consider this example:

In the octave (/ matlab) console:

```
octave:1> a = 1; b = 2; c = 11;
octave:2> a:b:c
    1    3    5    7    9   11
```

In the python3 interpreter:

```
>>> a = 1; b = 2; c = 11;
>>> list( range( a, c+b, b ) )
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```